# Printing the input to a Keras model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Is there any way I can print the input going into my Keras model?
I am not sure if the "batch_size" refers to the number of samples, or number of data points per sample. It would be great if I could print the input going into my Keras model.

Comment: `batch_size` refers to the number of samples propagated through the network. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) stack exchange answer

Comment: so, before feeding the data to the network you will convert the image data/numerical data into records(ie.., [784, ?]). In this case "?" represents the batch size. I would suggest you, convert the data as a batch generator and do for loop to feed into the NN model. Underneath data points are converted into a list of records and fed to the network. So, for your question it just an "array of list of records"

Answer (score 1):

Batch size is the number of samples which will pass through the network in one step. Hence on multiplying the number of steps with the batch size gives the total number of samples.

> batch_size = number_of_samples / number_of_steps

To get the input tensor of your Keras model :

```
input_tensor = model.input
```

To get the shape tensor from `input_tensor` :

```
shape_tensor = tf.shape( input_tensor )
```

Run the `shape_tensor` in a `tf.Session()` by **feeding some input** to the `input_tensor`:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    print( session( shape_tensor , feed_dict={ input_tensor:some_input } ) )
```

That will print the shape.